# How to read different numbers from users input? C++

Tags: c++

I need to read some data from user using cin to an array It's easy but the problem is that  I need the numbers to be different. Is there a way to do it fast without checking out the whole array (to see if there was such number or not) every time the user inputs a new number?

Comment: What may be in the input?

Comment: @GMichael Example input: 8 4 1 7 11 13 9 21 75 ... Integers, where the first integer is the number of all integers to be entered

Comment: If this is the case, I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Why would it be slow to check the array? You're not doing 975749394784 numbers I assume? If you were, then there might be other ways

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The thing is that the number of numbers can be huge that's why I think going through the array every time may slow down the program significantly

Comment: If you know the max number create an array of that size, initialize to zero and for every number check if array[number] == 0 { }else array[number] = 1 Very fast, a lot of memory used

Answer (score -1):

you can try std::find(). it works like a loop to check values in your arrays

here is the reference for find() function

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/